# How can i catch exceptions in a method that throws them(JAVA)?

Tags: class, methods, exception, compilation, throwable

I have a class with a method that throws some exceptions and catches them inside itself, but when i call it in my Main class they seem to not being catched.

An example about my problem:

```
public class Test {
 public static void method (int number) throws InvalidNumberException {
      try {
           if (number == 5) {
                throw new InvalidNumberException("Invalid number");
           }
      } catch (InvalidNumberException inv) {
           System.out.println(inv);
      }
 }
}

public class InvalidNumberException extends Exception {
 public InvalidNumberException (String s) {
      super(s);
 }
}



public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
       Test.method(5);
 }
}
```

When i try to compilate the last one i get this error:

Main.java:3: error: unreported exception InvalidNumberException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
          Test.method(5);

Is there a way to fix it without catching the exception in the Main class?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're catching the `InvalidNumberException` inside of `method`, there's no need for a `throws` clause, however, the existence of it mandates that calls to it must handle the exception. Thus, the compiler is expecting you to handle the exception in `main`.

To solve this, simply remove the `throws` clause modifying `method`, since you're already handling the exception inside.